# Java algorithm filling cells like an `Android - Flow` game

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have an issue.

We have a table `2xN` which have a linked nodes as `1,6 -> 1,1` and `2,6 -> 2,1` like a cilinder.

```
      -----------------------------------------------------
(1)->|  1,1    | 1,2    |  1,3   | 1,4    |  1,5   |  1,6   |  -> (1)
      ------------------------------------------------------
(2)->|   2,1   | 2,2    |  2,3   | 2,4    |  2,5   |  2,6   |  -> (2)
      ------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a **StartPoint1**  - is a point in cell `1,1` and **EndPoint1** in cell `2,6`
and  a **StartPoint12**  - is a point in cell `2,1` and **EndPoint2** in cell `2,5`

I want to find a combination of two pathes that fill all table on the way.

for example above is

> **(P1) = (1,1) -> (1,2) -> (1,3) -> (1,4) -> (1,5) -> (1,6) -> (2,6)**
>   **(P2) = (2,1) -> (2,2) -> (2,3) -> (2,4) -> (2,5)**

So, i walk around all table on two pathes (12 cells - 12 steps)

Now i stopped after filling the structure :

```
private static void buildGrid(int gridResolution) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridResolution; j++) {
            Node node = new Node();
            if (startPoint1.x == i && startPoint1.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 1);
                startNode1 = node;
            } else if (startPoint2.x == i && startPoint2.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 1);
                startNode2 = node;
            } else if (endPoint1.x == i && endPoint1.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 2);
                endNode1 = node;
            } else if (endPoint2.x == i && endPoint2.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 2);
                endNode2 = node;
            } else {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 0);
            }
            nodes[i][j] = node;

            Node leftNode = getLeftNode(i, j);
            Node topNode = getTopNode(i, j);
            if (leftNode != null) {
                node.left = leftNode;
                leftNode.right = node;
            }
            if (topNode != null) {
                node.top = topNode;
                topNode.bottom = node.top;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Node getTopNode(int i, int j) {
    return nodes[i - 1][j];
}

private static Node getLeftNode(int i, int j) {
    if (j - 1 > 0)
        return nodes[i][j - 1];
    else return null;
}

private static class Node {
    public PointM point;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node top;
    public Node bottom;

    public boolean isChecked;
}
```

And i doesn't know what i need to do after that. I stuck on this moment. As best and will circumvent this table. Perhaps it is what the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

For every cell you visit, mark it as visited.

From the cell you are right now, see which are the possible cells you could go to:
If there are no cells you could go to, then check if this is the end of the game. If not the end of the game, then this was a failure.

If there are cells you could visit, make a list of the cells to be visited and spawn a recursion for that cell. When that recursion finished, you have 2 choices: either the game was completed or that recursion got to a bad end. If it got to a bad end, then spawn a new recursion for the next available cell. No more available cells? stop.

Comment: Which part you didn't understand?

Comment: i need to recursive find path? so if i located in center cell i need to check all both located cells?

Comment: regardless of where you are, make a list of all available cells around the current cell. Then recursively call the path for every cell in the list.