# Android Flow game filling algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm

According to my question [Java algorithm filling cells like an `Android - Flow` game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919901/java-algorithm-filling-cells-like-an-android-flow-game)

[image: Game objective]

Suppose i have four points(two pairs) how i can check is the exist combination of pathes between points that filling all game board?

Like an right image, but with four points ( two pairs ).

> I need to check can i fill all game board with two arcs(path).

Now i stopped after filling the structure :

```
private static void buildGrid(int gridResolution) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridResolution; j++) {
            Node node = new Node();
            if (startPoint1.x == i && startPoint1.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 1);
                startNode1 = node;
            } else if (startPoint2.x == i && startPoint2.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 1);
                startNode2 = node;
            } else if (endPoint1.x == i && endPoint1.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 2);
                endNode1 = node;
            } else if (endPoint2.x == i && endPoint2.y == j) {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 2);
                endNode2 = node;
            } else {
                node.point = new PointM(new Point(i, j), 0);
            }
            nodes[i][j] = node;

            Node leftNode = getLeftNode(i, j);
            Node topNode = getTopNode(i, j);
            if (leftNode != null) {
                node.left = leftNode;
                leftNode.right = node;
            }
            if (topNode != null) {
                node.top = topNode;
                topNode.bottom = node.top;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Node getTopNode(int i, int j) {
    return nodes[i - 1][j];
}

private static Node getLeftNode(int i, int j) {
    if (j - 1 > 0)
        return nodes[i][j - 1];
    else return null;
}

private static class Node {
    public PointM point;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node top;
    public Node bottom;

    public boolean isChecked;
}
```

And i doesn't know what i need to do after that. I stuck on this moment. As best and will circumvent this table. Perhaps it is what the algorithm?

Comment: And i will be gratefull if you explain your downvotes...

Comment: Please post the specific code you are having problems with.

Comment: @AndrewArnold I provided a link to code at the top of the question.

Comment: No, you provided a link to another question. You need to put the relevant code in this question.

Comment: @AndrewArnold god... it's just copy-paste action...

Answer (score 2):

Personally, for building-grid purpose I'd *invert* your approach. So, instead of checking if for each pair a proper path exists, we will create grid which satisfies this condition.

So, the algorithm would look like this:

- Create 1st path using unmarked points. Then mark all points of path. Insert coins at starting and ending point of path.
- Create 2nd path using unmarked points. Then mark all points of path. Insert coins at starting and ending point of path.

...

- Stop when all point are marked.

Then you will have grid where for each pair, there is a proper path.

Here is an example of this algorithm:

[image: grid building]